# Retrieve UserID from AuthenticationStateProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am creating a to-do item where each item on creation belongs to a specific user. I am using the AspNetCore identity with a table AspNetUsers. I am trying to get the ID of the current user in an OnInitializedAsync method. I am running into a small problem. I found on another post that FirstOrDefault().Value will return the user Id, however, since my User model uses GUID as the UserID and the AspNetCore.Identity does not, I am running into an issue of how I could change the AspNetCore.Identity userID to a GUID. Other tables are reliant on the GUID type set for UserID (migration presents this error) and so I cannot change it. However, This might also not be the correct approach. I am wondering how I could retrieve the UserID correctly?

```
@inject AuthenticationStateProvider GetAuthenticationStateAsync

private Todo todoItem { get; set; } = new Todo ();

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    todoItem.owningUser = new User();
    var authstate = await GetAuthenticationStateAsync.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
    var user = authstate.User;
    var id = user.Claims.FirstOrDefault().Value;
    todoItem.owningUser.UserId = Guid.Parse(id); // did not work
}
```

Comment: Do you have the possibility to design ur tables?

Comment: AspNetUsers is a generated table but the Blazor template

Comment: What kind of output is it giving you, and what kind of output are you expecting? If you have everything set up to be of type GUID you shouldn't really walk into problems.

Comment: The AspNetUsers table I think is using a string not GUID. I am not sure how to change the AspNetUsers table to also use GUID

Comment: In that case, as mentioned before, if you have access to ur SQL Tables just change the datatype inside ur table. You might've done something wrong by accident when you applied the migrations.

Answer (score 0):

You should set a breakpoint to browse through the user object in VS.  Then you can see what claims are there, what they are called, etc.  If you are using standard Identity, then the following should work:

```
@inject AuthenticationStateProvider ASP

@code {
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var user = (await ASP.GetAuthenticationStateAsync()).User;
        var UserStringId = user.FindFirst(c => c.Type.Contains("nameidentifier"))?.Value;
        todoItem.owningUser.UserId = Guid.Parse(UserStringId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. In the case that my UserDTO model uses a GUID id from unique identification and .Value returns a string. How might I go about: todoItem.owningUser.UserId = UserId; ? I get an error saying cannot convert type string to Guid; rightfully so. Any recommendations on how to handle this?

Comment: Either convert the string to a Guid or convert the Guid to a string for the comparison?  Not sure which is cheaper in processor time.

Comment: @Krellex `var UserGuid = Guid.Parse(UserId);` should do it, I think.   I will edit my answer.  C# has very good documentation, if you google "C# convert string to Guid" you should get some joy.  However, I would just use a `string` in your `todoItem.owningUser.UserId` field itself rather than a Guid, since Blazor's default Identity system uses a `string` anyway.

Comment: Guid.Parse did not seem to work for me, keeps throwing me errors of not being able to correctly convert. The string inside AspNetUsers i think does not correctly map to a GUID which is what is causing the error.

Comment: AspNetUsers Id field is by default stored in SQL as nvarchar(450), which is a string.  But it is, by default, a Guid, and will parse as such.  What value, exactly is in `id` when you set a breakpoint at your conversion line?